# "Action" in indexController not rendering in view

Tags: php, templates, zend-framework

I have an existing Zend 1.12 project with modules et al that I am trying to simply add a view to create another web page.  So there is a controller called "Management" that has an index action, the default of course, and the correct view page called index.phtml.  That is all fine and works inside the entire project/website.

class Management_IndexController extends Default_Controller_Action {

```
function indexAction() {
    $this->view->headStyle()->appendFile('contact.css', 'contact')
    ->appendFile('message.css')
    ;
           $this->setLayout('management');
           $this->view->headTitle()->set('Management');
    $message = new Com_Ui_Message();
    $request  = $this->_request;
    $settings=new Com_Data();
            $content=new Com_Data();
    $data = new Com_Data($request->getPost());
    $this->setFocus('#name');

}

function chatAction() {

    $this->view->headStyle()->appendFile('contact.css', 'contact')
    ->appendFile('message.css')
    ;

 $this->view->testMessage = "test";

}
```

}

So if I browse to http://www.bmcmusicgroup.com/management I see the default action public function, and that is all good.  If I try to add another public function called chatAction inside of the management controller, and create a view page called chat.phtml in the appropriate folder where the index.phtml file is (the management index.phtml file), and then point my browser to http://www.bmcmusicgroup.com/management/chat I get nothing.

This is an existing site that I am trying decipher.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It can be a router, or a plugin that redefined the actions

Comment: Or ine the Default_Controller_Action, it can be a predispatch() or init() that redefined the actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your url to the following and you should see the page: http://www.bmcmusicgroup.com/management/index/chat. The URL you entered (http://www.bmcmusicgroup.com/management/chat) decomposes like so:

Module: management;
Controller: chat;
Action: index

Comment: That was it!  Muchos gracias Tim (and others who commented/helped). Now I can start carving some web pages out!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you wouldn't mind approving the answer, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: approved, thanks again Tim - may post another MVC question related to the same site so not sure if I should post new or add in this comment.

Comment: But ... trying to duplicate this "page" http://www.bmcmusicgroup.com/bmc-music-live but the module is musiclive and the submenu pages off of this menu item have URL of for example http://www.bmcmusicgroup.com/episode-listings where this a "view" file called episode-listings.phtml.  So where does the bmc-music-live part com into play??

Comment: If you want to redirect the page to musiclive, you may need to use an Apache rewrite to do so (assuming you use Apache for your web server). Alternatively, you could overwrite the Zend router; however, that would be a challenging task.

Comment: I have been fiddling with stuff thanks to your advice and it seems to be doing the trick for me.  Most of the data-getting and content-rendering (vids and music snippets) has already been done so I am co-opting that work into a few new web pages.  Much appreciated for your feedback!  Will comment with my results.